# How can I define either null or zero for COALESCE?

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

As you know, `COALESCE` returns the first not-`null` value. Now I need to say, either not-`null` or not-`0`. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT COALESCE(qa2.AcceptedAnswer, qa.AcceptedAnswer) AcceptedAnswer
FROM qanda
```

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(qa2.AcceptedAnswer, 0), qa.AcceptedAnswer) as AcceptedAnswer
FROM qanda;
```

Personally, I prefer a `CASE` expression because I find the intention more explicit:

```
select (case when qa2.AcceptedAnswer <> 0 then qa2.AcceptedAnswer
             else qa.AcceptedAnswer
        end) as AcceptedAnswer
```

Note that an explicit `NULL` comparison is not needed; the `<>` takes care of that.

Comment: Your first solution is wrong. Since `SELECT COALESCE(0, 1)` returns `0`. While my question says *"I need to behave with `0` like `NULL`, so `0` should be ignored"*

Comment: @MartinAJ: `nullif(0, 0)` yields `NULL` ,so `coalesce(nullif(0, 0), 1)` = `coalesce(NULL, 1)` returns `1`, not `0`. You might confuse [`nullif()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) with [`ifnull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) (Note the different positions of "if" in the function names.).

Comment: No, @Gordon's first solution is correct. "If qa2 is zero, treat it as NULL". If qa2 = 0 and qa = 1, the first coalesce will be COALESCE(NULL, 1) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `CASE WHEN` in `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(CASE WHEN qa2.AcceptedAnswer<> 0 THEN qa2.AcceptedAnswer END
           ,CASE WHEN qa.AcceptedAnswer <> 0 THEN qa.AcceptedAnswer END)
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcf263d/5)